# MIPS32: Fetch Address Not Aligned on Word Boundary

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, runtime-error, mips

I'm new to MIPs programming and i'm trying to iterate through an array using a loop to play midi notes using syscall.

When running the code, I get the error fetch address not aligned on word boundary.

Runtime exception at 0x00400038: address out of range 0x00000190.

Here is the code:

```
.data 
my_notes: .word 39, 44, 47, 46, 44, 51, 49, 46, 44, 47, 46, 42, 45, 39, 39, 44, 47, 46, 44, 51, 54, 53, 52, 48, 52, 51, 50, 38, 47, 44  
note_durations: .word 400, 400, 400, 400, 800, 400, 1200, 1200, 400, 400, 400, 800, 400, 2000, 400, 400, 400, 400, 800, 400, 800, 400, 800, 400, 400, 400, 400, 800, 400, 2000
iterator:  .word 0
arraySize: .word 30

.text 
main:
la $t0, my_notes
lw $t1, iterator
lw $t2, arraySize
lw $t3, note_durations

loop:
bgt $t1, $t2, end   # if (iterator > arraySize) goto end
sll $t4, $t1, 2     # 4*i
addu $t6, $t4, $t3  # $t6 = note duration memory address + 4i
addu $t4, $t4, $t0  # $t4 = note memory address + 4i
lw $t5, 0($t4)      # store in $t5 memory address of note[4i]
lw $t7, 0($t6)      # store in $t7 memory address of note_duration[4i]

li $v0, 33          # Load service number to play a note
la $a0, ($t5)        # pitch
la $a1, ($t7)       # duration
la $a2, 1       # instrument
la $a3, 80      # volume
syscall 
addi $t1, $t1, 1     # iterate +1
j loop

end:
```

Comment: Using the debugger, which instruction is faulting, and what address is in the register?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: BTW, you know MIPS requires word accesses to be word-aligned, right?  https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Alignment

Comment: line 19:    lw $t7, 0($t6)

Comment: `lw $t3, note_durations` loads the data, not the address.  Use the debugger to look at the values in registers.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I missed lw $t3, note_durations should be la $t3 note_durations

Comment: You can use `.equ` to define constants for use as immediates, instead of loading from memory.  For example, it's super-weird to store a `0` in memory just so you can initialize a loop counter.  You can init a counter with `addiu $t1, $zero, 0`.  MIPS has an architectural zero-register.  (Or write `move $t1, $zero` to let the assembler do that for you; move is a pseudo-instruction.)  Or more simply, there's a `li` pseudo-instruction for load-immediate (which probably assembles to fewer instructions than `lw` with a symbol instead of a register address).

Comment: http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm